# Integration of $1/(1+\sin 2x)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Okay so I've to integrate $$∫\frac{dx}{(1+\sin 2x)}$$ but I'm not getting any further from here $$∫\frac{dx}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}.$$ Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{1+\sin 2x}dx=\int\frac{1}{1+\sin 2x}\cdot\frac{1-\sin 2x}{1-\sin 2x}dx=\int\frac{1-\sin 2x}{\cos^2 2x}dx$

$\displaystyle=\int\left(\sec^2 2x-\sec 2x\tan 2x\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\big(\tan 2x-\sec 2x\big)+C$

Comment: You saved my life bro. Yours is the precise answer I was looking for. Don't you think my question doesn't deserve any downvotes? Kindly upvote it if you think it deserved it

Comment: @Zlatan It was a trivial question, why would it deserve an upvote?

Answer (score 5):

Let $$I = \int\frac{1}{1+\sin 2x}dx $$

Put $\displaystyle 2x=\frac{\pi}{2}-2t\;,$ Then $dx = -dt$

So $$I = -\int\frac{1}{1+\cos 2t}dt = -\int\frac{1}{2\cos^2 t}dt = -\frac{1}{2}\int \sec^2 tdt = -\frac{1}{2}\tan t+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = \int\frac{1}{1+\sin 2x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: $dx=-dt$ you mean

Comment: Yes  David Quinn 2 I have edited.

Answer (score 3):

see my nice answer using OP's step:

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+\sin 2x}
=\int \frac{dx}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2}$$$$=\int \frac{dx}{\cos^2 x(1+\tan x)^2}=\int \frac{\sec^2 xdx}{(1+\tan x)^2}$$
$$=\int \frac{d(1+\tan x)}{(1+\tan x)^2}=-\frac{1}{1+\tan x}+C$$

Comment: who has down voted my answer & why?

Comment: It's a very good answer, so I don't understand why someone would downvote it.  (That's what happens sometimes on MSE, though.)

Answer (score 1):

**An other way**

Let $x=\arctan u$, then $\sin(2x)=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$,
$$...=\int^{\tan(x)}\frac{1+u^2}{1+u^2+2u}\mathrm d u=\int^{\tan(x)}\frac{1+u^2}{(1+u)^2}\mathrm d u.$$
Use the fact that $1+u^2=(1+u)^2-2u$ and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, from where you left off, the integrand can be written as $$\frac 12\csc^2(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$$ so you end up with $$-\frac 12\cot(x+\frac{\pi}{4})+c$$ which is equivalent to @juantheron's answer