# Find $\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos2x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Find $\int \frac{dx}{1 +\cos{2x}}$

I did this integral with the method  [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922489/integration-of-1-1-sin-2x?noredirect=1)

I have question with this step

$$\int\frac{dx}{1+\cos2x}=\int \frac{1}{1+\cos2x}\frac{1-\cos2x}{1-\cos2x}\,dx$$

Here when $x=\pi k$ it divides $0$ how can you explain this step?

Comment: If you've put no restrictions on the domain of the integrand, then you can't, since the problem of finding an antiderivative presumably implies finding one that's differentiable over the domain of the integrand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether or not you are interested in this, but you can *avoid* that step:\begin{align}\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+\cos(2x)}&=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}\\&=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{2\cos^2(x)}\\&=\frac12\int\sec^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac12\tan(x).\end{align}Anyway, whatever the method that you use, you can always check that the final answer works by differentiating it and checking that what you get is $\frac1{1+\cos(2x)}$.

Comment: That's really clever!

Answer (score 0):

You can "cleverly" change the domain to argue that the method works.

That is, if the function is let's say defined on $\mathbb R$, you may argue that we are performing the integral on the domain
$$\mathbb R\backslash \{k\pi: k\in \mathbb N\}$$
or
$$\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb N} (k\pi,(k+1)\pi)$$
and argue that the integral will be the same since you have removed a set from $\mathbb R$ whose measure is $0$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks I don't know yet sets whose measure is $0$ but for the future it will be helpful.

Comment: @unit1991 oh don't pay any attention to that line if you don't understand it. It basically means that the set $\{k\pi: k\in \mathbb N\}$ doesn't *weigh* anything in $\mathbb N$. But forget that. You intuitively do understand that integrating a function on a domain and integrating it on a domain minus one point are the same, right? Just look at it in terms of area. What does the area under the curve look like if you pull all of $\mathbb N$ out of $\mathbb R$ (you are just removing lines from an area!)? Could I make myself clear? Feel free to say no.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Yes it makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get $k$ from, but you can solve this integral using trig identities.

First, recall that $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ and $1 = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)$, so we can rewrite $\int\frac{dx}{1+\cos(2x)}$ as $\int\frac{dx}{\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}$ which simplifies as $\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dx}{\cos^2(x)}$. This simplifies as $\frac{1}{2}\tan(x) + C$.